# Pandas merge not working after update, forced to use concat in v2.0.3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I recently updated Pandas and an old script is no longer working for:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['UTC'])[strct]
```

'strct' = string, 'UTC' = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='60mins')

How do I achieve the same using concat?

ERROR message: ValueError: You are trying to merge on datetime64[ns] and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Comment: No error message?

Comment: sorry... edited now

Comment: Make sure your merging key(s) have the same type. Convert the object to datetime with `pd.to_datetime` (e.g. `df1['UTC'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['UTC'])`)

Comment: Does merge work if you use `df.key.astype('datetime64[ns]')` on whichever is the object of 'df1' and `df2`?